# How to aggregate other columns based on unique values of 1 column in data frame

Tags: pyspark

I have a table like this, and I want to find the unique `Name` and aggregate the value of `Value1` (min value) and `Value2` (max value). Meaning for each unique `Name`, I want to get the min of Value 1 of that name and max of Value 2

Input:

| Name | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 1 | 2 |
| John | 3 | 4 |
| Mary | 2 | 1 |
| Mary | 4 | 3 |
| Peter | 3 | 6 |

Output:

| Name | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 1 | 4 |
| Mary | 2 | 3 |
| Peter | 3 | 6 |

I see I can get unique column of a data frame by using `df.select('Name ').distinct().collect()`

But my question is how can I aggregate the min/max of other columns after I get the unique values of `Name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [groupBy](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.groupBy.html) and aggregate by [min](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.min.html#pyspark.sql.functions.min) and [max](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.max.html#pyspark.sql.functions.max):

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[["John",1,2],["John",3,4],["Mary",2,1],["Mary",4,3],["Peter",3,6]], schema=["Name","Value1","Value2"])

df = df.groupBy("Name") \
      .agg( \
          F.min("Value1").alias("Value1"), \
          F.max("Value2").alias("Value2") \
      )
```

Output:

```
+-----+------+------+
|Name |Value1|Value2|
+-----+------+------+
|Mary |2     |3     |
|John |1     |4     |
|Peter|3     |6     |
+-----+------+------+
```